# "Sie bleiben überhaupt gern unter sich."

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> Die Meiers bleiben sehr gern unter sich.
>
> Die Meiers bleiben überhaupt sehr gern unter sich.

I know that both mean something like

> The Meiers [very much] like to keep to themselves.

I just can't figure out what the *überhaupt* contributes here.  In other words, why/how would the second German sentence above fall short?  Why would the speaker feel compelled to insert the *überhaupt*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Überhaupt" here indicates that the statement is a generalization.

A possible example with some more context is:

> Die Meiers nehmen nicht am gemeinsamen Abendessen teil. Sie bleiben überhaupt gern unter sich.

Here a possible translation could be "generally". So the above example translates to:

> The Meiers don't participate in the joint dinner. They generally prefer to stay among themselves.

Comment: Hmmm... I would have used *anyway*, but that is perhaps more a translation of *sowieso*.

Comment: I'd note that *überhaupt* with this meaning is never used on its own. It's always preceded by a concrete example, just like @RHa wrote in the answer.